# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') with ChartJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing this issue while trying to create a donut chart using react-chartjs-2. I used console.log() to test whether every array had a value, and every single array returned values they are supposed to. I also tried rewriting the code using for loops instead of map() to make sure it's not the problem. I tried loading only this component to make sure no other component is generating the problem.

You see here a reproduction of the same error, using minimalistic code, thanks:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-glitter-5tqjr9?file=/src/SalesDoughnutChart.js

Comment: You're using a single colour for all segments of the donut. But typically, a donut chart would have different colours for each segment. The backgroundColor property in datasets expects an array of colors when you have multiple data points.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tried it, still the same issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry that didn't help. Maybe try setting some default values for chartData when you initialize its state. This way, the component receives some valid data structure even before the useEffect runs. e.g.
```const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{ label: "", data: [], backgroundColor: [], borderColor: [] }]
});
```

Comment: I new error emerges, "arc" is not a registered element. at Registry._get. I'll probably just try another library. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Sorry to hear that: A clean install might help. Otherwise, if you're gonna use a different library, recharts and victory are pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial state for `chartData` is empty, which means the `datasets` value isn't available on the very initial rendering.

To get around of this issue, you can initialize the `chartData` state with empty `datasets` array as how the `v4` version of the example code does --

```
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    datasets: []
  });
```

See the example from official documentation here: https://react-chartjs-2.netlify.app/docs/migration-to-v4/#drawing-charts-with-gradients

For your follow-up question about `arc` not a register element, you need the follow code to "register" to ChartJS for them to know what you are using --

```
import {Chart, ArcElement} from 'chart.js'
Chart.register(ArcElement);
```

Read more about registering the element here: https://react-chartjs-2.netlify.app/faq/registered-element

Your codesandbox but the working version here - https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-kapitsa-plyzfj?file=/src/SalesDoughnutChart.js:206-275

Comment: Man you un-ruined my day, thanks a lot for the time and the help.